# How do I parse an Enum with Aeson?

Tags: haskell, aeson

I have a type representing enum:

```
data FooBar = Foo | Bar deriving (Show, Enum)
```

I want to parse this from numeric values in JSON using aeson, i.e. a 0 in the JSON file should return Foo, a 1 should return Bar.

My best attempt is the following:

```
instance FromJSON FooBar where
    parseJSON (Number n) = return (case maybeInt of
                                     Just i -> (toEnum i)
                                     Nothing -> ??)
      where maybeInt = (Scientific.toBoundedInteger n)
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

But this doesn't really handle the error case. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Fail as F

data FooBar = Foo | Bar deriving (Show, Enum, Bounded) -- note Bounded instance

instance FromJSON FooBar where
  -- parseJSON is the one for Int, which internally uses the Scientific function
  -- you used yourself
  -- Control.Monad.Fail.MonadFail Parser, so safeToEnum may have type
  -- safeToEnum :: Int -> Parser FooBar
  -- (Control.Monad.<=<) is (.) but in the Kleisli category
  -- (<=<) :: (b -> m c) -> (a -> m b) -> (a -> m c)
  -- (.)   :: (b ->   c) -> (a ->   b) -> (a ->   c)
  -- (f <=< g) x = do { x' <- g x;   f x' }
  -- (f  .  g) x = let  x' =  g x in f x'
  -- it's always nice when something can just be a composition of smaller things
  parseJSON = safeToEnum <=< parseJSON

-- using fail over mzero gives nicer error messages
-- (mzero = fail "mzero" for Parser, which is *very* informative)
-- this is a reusable function that can also produce Maybes, Eithers, etc.
-- depending on context, and works for lots of enumerations, since
-- many are Bounded (e.g. Bool, Char, etc.), and user-defined ones almost
-- always are.
safeToEnum :: (Enum a, Bounded a, MonadFail m) => Int -> m a
safeToEnum i = if i < min
                  then F.fail $ show i ++ " is less than the minimum, " ++ show min
                  else if i > max
                          then F.fail $ show i ++ " is greater than the maximum, " ++ show max
                          else return result
  where min = fromEnum (minBound `asTypeOf` result)
        max = fromEnum (maxBound `asTypeOf` result)
        result = toEnum i -- hooray laziness
        -- defining result and using it in min and max is safe, because
        -- asTypeOf ignores the second argument; it's just there to clarify
        -- to the type system which instance of Bounded we're talking about
        -- it's not strictly necessary in GHC Haskell, because ScopedTypeVariables
        -- would allow min = fromEnum (maxBound :: a)
        -- but using asTypeOf keeps the language extension count down
```

Which produces such results as:

```
> data D = D { dInt :: Int, dFooBar :: FooBar } deriving (Show, Generic, FromJSON)

> safeToEnum 3 :: Maybe FooBar
Nothing
-- discards error messages
> safeToEnum 3 :: Result FooBar
Error "3 is greater than the maximum, 1"
-- keeps error messages

> eitherDecode "{ \"dInt\": 5, \"dFooBar\": 1 }" :: Either String D
Right (D {dInt = 5, dFooBar = Bar})
> eitherDecode "{ \"dInt\": 0, \"dFooBar\": -10 }" :: Either String D
Left "Error in $.dFooBar: -10 is less than the minimum, 0"
-- safeToEnum doesn't cause runtime errors like toEnum
> toEnum 10 :: FooBar
*** Exception: toEnum{FooBar}: tag (10) is outside of enumeration's range (0,1)
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  error, called at T.hs:8:41 in main:T

> eitherDecode "{ \"dInt\": 0, \"dFooBar\": 0.5 }" :: Either String D
Left "Error in $.dFooBar: Int is either floating or will cause over or underflow: 0.5"
-- Scientific.toBoundedInteger is there for you, too
> eitherDecode "{ \"dInt\": 0, \"dFooBar\": 1e42 }" :: Either String D
Left "Error in $.dFooBar: Int is either floating or will cause over or underflow: 1.0e42"
-- and aeson tags the errors with their location
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that your parser is a `Monad` (or, to be precise, a [`MonadFail`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Control-Monad-Fail.html#t:MonadFail)), so you can make it fail using the `fail` method. With it your code will look something like this:

```
instance FromJSON FooBar where
    parseJSON (Number n) =
      case maybeInt of
        Just i -> return (toEnum i)
        Nothing -> fail "Out of bounds"
      where
        maybeInt = Scientific.toBoundedInteger n
    parseJSON _ = mzero
```

Comment: Oh and you might want to consider using [`aeson-better-errors`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-better-errors) to build your JSON parsers.

Comment: "Out of bounds" is the wrong error message: the test is just making sure that the number is an integer, not whether it's in bounds. Further, this will cause a runtime `error` if the number is an integer that's actually out of bounds instead of just failing the parse.

Comment: The function is literally called “to bounded integer”, so it does check the bounds. The detail you are referring to is that it is a different bound that is checked (i.e. it checks that the number fits into an `Int`), but I am merely answering the question that was asked: how to make a parser fail. I think that debugging your own code is much more instructive than having all your mistakes pointed out at once, when you didn’t ask for it.